# Error: Cannot convert from method group to string

Tags: c#, c#-record-type

I'm following a tutorial and getting an error:

> "cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'".

I'm using the .net 5.0 framework in the cs project.

Below is the code. The error is coming on the line:

```
yield return new Student(_names[index].First, _names[index].Last);
```

StudentRepository.cs

```
public record Name(string First, string Last);

public class StudentRepository: IRepository<Student>
{
    private Name[] _names = new Name[10];

    public StudentRepository()
    {
        _names[0] = new("Steve", "Smith");
        _names[1] = new("Chad", "Smith");
        _names[2] = new("Ben", "Smith");
        _names[3] = new("Eric", "Smith");
        _names[4] = new("Julie", "Lerman");
        _names[5] = new("David", "Starr");
        _names[6] = new("Aaron", "Skonnard");
        _names[7] = new("Aaron", "Stewart");
        _names[8] = new("Aaron", "Powell");
        _names[9] = new("Aaron", "Frost");
    }

    public IEnumerable<Student> List()
    {
        int index = 0;
        while (index < _names.Length)
        {
            yield return new Student(_names[index].First, _names[index].Last);
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Student.cs

```
public class Student: IComparable<Student>
{
    public static int studentCounter = 0;

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Student(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        studentCounter++;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
    }

    public int CompareTo(Student other)
    {
        if (other is null) return 1;

        if (other.LastName == this.LastName)
        {
            return this.FirstName.CompareTo(other.FirstName);
        }
        return this.LastName.CompareTo(other.LastName);
    }
}
```

Comment: @OlivierRogier - might have to do with using the record type?

Comment: @OlivierRogier the members are already public

Comment: @.rds80 What happens if you use for example MyFirst and MyLast instead of First and Last (using F2 refactoring tool)?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error: code just works as expected...

Comment: Are you certain the `yield` line is the source of the error?

Comment: Does renaming First and Last into `FirstName` and `LastName` resolve the issue? If so this might be a bug.

Comment: @rds80 I ran your code but everything is went well and I couldn't any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the compiler might be confusing your First-property with the First() method of Linq. Are you using .NET 5 or a preview version of .NET 6?

You can try changing the names of First and Last to FirstName and LastName to see if it has to do with this, or remove the System.Linq using on top of your file.